# Better alternative to several ||s in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using Javascript, and I'd like to make one IF statement that will check one variable against multiple strings using the least amount of code as possible.
This is what I used:

```
if (string == "1" || string == "2" || string == "3" || string == "4") {
console.log("This should execute when string is 1, 2, 3, or 4");
}
```

How would I go about this same thing with the least amount of code as possible? I am using Javascript.

Comment: @NathanHughes While the solutions may be the same, this question isn't a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @NathanHughes The purpose is to not have duplicate solutions to the same problem persist. This is an entirely different problem—one that future users are likely to encounter—so having a canonical question and solution exist for it is valuable. If this same problem has been posed and solved before, please mark that as duplicate—but not different problems with the same answer.

Comment: @NathanHughes Please refer to this post on meta: [Does the same answer imply that the questions should be closed as duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate)

Comment: @Sean nice reasoning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `.includes`

```
if (["1", "2", "3", "4"].includes(string)) {
  console.log("This should execute when string is 1, 2, 3, or 4")
}
```